# Creating a mysql database and sharing it remotely

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, remote-access

I need to create a database and share it remotely over the internet. The username and password of the database will be used by a friend to store data from another program. I have been using mysql workbench but I don't exactly know how to allow remote access to the database. Step by step instructions would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Oh alright! Thanks a lot!